# JS Split multiple delimiters and get delimiters into input value

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I'm asking you today for a little problem :

I have to live control capitalization/no capitalization with js on an input text field like this:

- 1st character of the entire string must be uppercase
- 1st character of each word (after space or hyphen) is free (lowercase or uppercase allowed)
- All the nother characters must be lowercase

**Desired Output: Grand-Father is Nice**

I'm not a specialist of JS, i'm using split function, here is my code :

```
$('#name').on('input change',function() {

  var arr1 = $(this).val().split(/[- ]/);
  var result1 = "";
  for (var x=0; x<arr1.length; x++)
    result1+=arr1[x].substring(0,1)+arr1[x].substring(1).toLowerCase()+" ";
  var res1 = result1.substring(0, result1.length-1);

  var _txt = res1.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + res1.slice(1);
  $('#name').val(_txt);

});
```

The script works but I would like to output the real delimiter found in string, even if it's a space " " or hyphen "-". Actually i can show only space. How can i solve it ?

**Actual output: Grand Father is Nice**

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User `String.replace()` with a RegExp and a callback.

If you know what are your delimiters, you can search for all characters that are no the delimiters, and format them:

```js
var input = 'ègrand-Father is NièCe';

var d = '[^\s\-]'; // not space or dash

var result = input.replace(new RegExp('('+ d +')(' + d + '+)', 'g'), function(m, p1, p2, i) {
  var end = p2.toLowerCase();
  var start = i === 0 ? p1.toUpperCase() : p1;
  
  return start + end;
});

console.log(result);
```

If the target browsers support it (Chrome does) or you use a transpiler, such as Babel ([plugin](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-plugin-proposal-unicode-property-regex/README.md)), you can use [Unicode property escapes in regular expressions](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-unicode-property-escapes) (`\p`):

```js
var input = 'ègrand-Father is NièCe';

var result = input.replace(/(\p{L})(\p{L}+)/gu, function(m, p1, p2, i) {
  var end = p2.toLowerCase();
  var start = i === 0 ? p1.toUpperCase() : p1;
  
  return start + end;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Nice answer, thank you, but i have to consider special characters like è,à,è... in input text

Comment: Updated to include special characters.

Comment: Sorry : "SyntaxError: invalid identity escape in regular expression"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your aim is, but let's give it a shot.
This is how you can make all non-first letters be lowercase

```
let sentence = "this is wRoNg SenTEnce."
sentence.split(" ").map(word => word.charAt(0) + word.slice(1).toLowerCase()).join(" ")
```

This is how you can make first letter capital:

```
let sentence = "also Wrong sentence"
sentence.charAt(0).toUpperCase()
```